# compile error using qFromBigEndian

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I'm trying to use qFromBigEndian to read a 32-bit int from a byte stream received over a udp socket.

```
void processData(uchar *data)
{
  qint32 addr;
  addr = qFromBigEndian(data);
}
```

Compiling this gives the following error: 
  **error: invalid conversion from 'uchar*' to 'qint32'**

The Qt documentation says:

**T qFromBigEndian ( const uchar * src )**

*`Reads a big-endian number from memory location src and returns the number in the host byte order representation. Note: Template type T can either be a qint16, qint32 or qint64.`*

Obviously I'm doing something a bit silly and I am already hanging my head in shame.  Can someone please explain my obvious mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `qFromBigEndian(const uchar *src)` is a function template.

You're missing the template parameter, use

```
addr = qFromBigEndian<qint32>(data);
```

instead, and things will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks very much.  That's sorted now.